# Why is PasswordFor inside FancyBox showing my password in plain text?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, passwords, fancybox

I take it that this should handle masking my typed in password. But when I type in my password, it shows up as plain text.

```
<tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td>
        @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password)</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: < input id="Password" name="Password" type="password" / > ... The fields are shown in FancyBox (jQuery plugin modal pop). When I submit the form and have it redirect back to the View itself, it works properly and I get the HTML above. So in short, plain text when in FancyBox, masked text when in regular web page.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with FancyBox.

Comment: I agree. Well I added: new {type = "Password"} to the PasswordFor and it worked. I guess FancyBox and HtmlHelpers don't play nice together.

Comment: This is not fancyBox issue - http://jsfiddle.net/8Px2m/

Answer (score 0):

Use this solution, it will work for you.

```
 <tr>
     <td>Password:</td>
       <td>
            @Html.Password("password", null, new { style = "float:none;margin:0;" })
       </td>
  </tr>
```